# Toggle visibility of html elements using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a html dom structure like this. I have used the ng-click to toggle the visibility of the DOM structure. For example if I am clicking  in menu1 and if it is not visible it will be make visible. This is working perfectly . But I came across a scenerio where I need to close menu2(if it is open) on clicking menu1 & vice versa. Is is possible to accomplish  using ng-click & ng-show

```
<span ng-click ="menu1 = !menu1">
      <div ng-show="menu1">
             //Rest of DOM element
     </div>
 </span>

  <span ng-click ="menu2 = !menu2">
        <div ng-show =menu2>
    //Rest of DOM element
    </div>
  </span>
```

Comment: Can you add more details? What do you mean by clicking in menu1? Where is menu1?

Answer (score 0):

Below I will provide you a sample. I have provided two button, by clicking on each button it hide and show its respective content
HTML :

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggleCustom()">Custom</button>
    <span ng-hide="custom">From:
        <input type="text" id="from" />
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="custom">To:
        <input type="text" id="to" />
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom2"></span>
    <button ng-click="toggleCustom2()">Custom</button>
    <span ng-hide="custom2">From:
        <input type="text" id="from" />
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="custom2">To:
        <input type="text" id="to" />
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom2"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
 angular.module('ngToggle', []).controller('myAppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.custom = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
        $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    };
     $scope.custom2 = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom2 = function() {
        $scope.custom2 = $scope.custom2 === false ? true: false;
     };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-click="menuToggle(1)">
    <div ng-show="menu1">...</div>
</span>

<span ng-click="menuToggle(2)">
    <div ng-show="menu2">...</div>
</span>
```

And in controller (or inline inside ng-click but you'd be better off having it in the controller (or directive depending on your code structure))

```
$scope.menuToggle = function(menu) {
    $scope.menu1 = (!$scope.menu1 && menu === 1);
    $scope.menu2 = (!$scope.menu2 && menu === 2);
};
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want this scenario:
When component/page/whatever is loaded, nothing is open (or you could set a default by settings '$scope.menu1 = true;' in controller). Then, if you would press menu1 span, menu1 would open. If you then press menu1 again, it would close. If you instead press menu2, menu1 is closed and menu2 opened.

In the future, try to be a bit more descriptive with your questions. Hope it works out!